# How to automatically create model from database using PetaPoco library?

Tags: c#, .net, orm, petapoco

I have a table in my database for which I want to create a model class with getters and setters. For most of the tasks in my project, I am using PetaPoco. I created models manually, but few tables have lots of columns.

Is there any way to create a model from a database using PetaPoco?

Comment: t4 templates from peta poco can't do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PetaPoco has T4 Visual Studio templates** that should do this for you. If you don't want to have them all generated, just use the template and then copy those classes from the resulting *.cs file that you want.

You'll find templates on [PetaPoco's GitHub code repo](https://github.com/toptensoftware/PetaPoco/tree/master/PetaPoco/Models/Generated).

Adding templates to your project can be done in two ways:

1. copying files manually
2. using NuGet in the package console or using Visual Studio Package Manager. Details [on NuGet site](http://nuget.org/packages/PetaPoco)

I would recommend the second option, because you can set your packages to auto download before build when not present (part of your CVS).

Comment: I used Database.tt which generated DAL for me. From that list, which one to use for creating a Class for a Table?

Comment: @RPK: What do you mean by _from that list_? What list? By default it should generate Database class and schema classes. AFAIK. I write manual POCOs myself but by the quick glance of the templates, table classes should be generated and contained in the resulting `Database.cs` file.

Comment: By the list I mean the .tt shown in the link you gave me. I also manually write POCOs but I want to add one using T4. Which T4 template to run? Will it disturb existing POCOs?

Comment: @RPK: There's just one `*.tt` file. `Database.tt`. The other two are `*.ttinclude` files that `Database.tt` uses. So you need to copy all three to some folder in your project and include them all in your Project. You will have to set some variables in the `Database.tt` so it will be able to connect to your data store. When you will save the file, VS will automatically run it and produce the resulting `Database.cs` for you.

Comment: I already did that and it created Database.cs for me. But I want to know how to create the Models of other tables in my database. For example, I have a Customer table and I expect PetaPoco to create Customer.cs clss with getters and setters.

Comment: @RPK: All classes are generated it's just that they're all contained in the same source file *Database.cs*. Look inside and you'll see there are several classes each related to one of the tables in your database. Unless you're using different databases, this should do it all for you.

Answer (score 9):

I highly recommend you use the T4 templates as it will make the process much faster as well as add additional functionality.

The fastest way is to open the "Package Manager Console" (Tools > Library Package Manger > Package Manger Console), make sure that your project is selected in the "Default project" drop down and run:

```
PM>install-package petapoco
```

This will create a folder called "Models" and a sub folder called "Generated". In the "Generated" folder, open the "Database.tt" file and setup the information. Refer to http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/ for information about setting this up.

Once you successfully setup the T4 template, it will generate a code file called "Database.cs" with all your objects in your database. What's generated are "partial classes". The key here is that **you should NOT modify** any object in this file. Instead, you will create a new partial class **in the same namespace** that you can then implement more logic to. Move/update your existing objects to confirm to the new setup.

Another option is to create some TSQL to generate some code. Here is a **very crude** example of something I've used in the past to generate interfaces for my PetaPoco tables.

```
declare @script nvarchar(max);
declare @table nvarchar(256);

set @table = 'YourTableName'

set @script = 'public interface I' + @table + '{' + char(10);
SELECT
    @script = @script + 
        CASE
            WHEN st.Name IN ('int') AND c.is_nullable = 0 THEN 'int'
            WHEN st.name in ('smallint')  AND c.is_nullable = 0 THEN 'short'
            WHEN st.name IN ('bigint') AND c.is_nullable = 0  THEN 'long'
            WHEN st.name IN ('varchar','nvarchar','sysname') THEN 'string'
            WHEN st.Name IN ('datetime') AND c.is_nullable = 0 THEN 'DateTime'
            WHEN st.Name IN ('bit') AND c.is_nullable = 0 THEN 'bool'
            WHEN st.Name IN ('decimal') AND c.is_nullable = 0 THEN 'decimal'
            /* NULLABLE VALUES */
            WHEN st.Name IN ('int') AND c.is_nullable = 1 THEN 'int?'
            WHEN st.name in ('smallint')  AND c.is_nullable = 1 THEN 'short?'
            WHEN st.name IN ('bigint') AND c.is_nullable = 1  THEN 'long?'
            WHEN st.name IN ('varchar','nvarchar','sysname') AND c.is_nullable = 1 THEN 'string?'
            WHEN st.Name IN ('datetime') AND c.is_nullable = 1 THEN 'DateTime?'
            WHEN st.Name IN ('bit') AND c.is_nullable = 1 THEN 'bool?'
            WHEN st.Name IN ('decimal') AND c.is_nullable = 1 THEN 'decimal?'   
            --WHEN st.name IN('sysname') AND c.is_nullable = 1 THEN 'string?'       
            ELSE 'UNKOWN-' + st.name
        END
    + ' ' + c.name + '{get;set;}' + char(10)
FROM sys.tables t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c
ON t.object_id = c.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types st
ON st.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
WHERE t.name = @table

print @script + '}'
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx on TSQL May I ask why there is no implementation for FLOAT type in SQL, did You forgot FLOAT or there is other reasons ?

Comment: Glad to help. This was just a quick and dirty example of a way one could extract the information from the DB. You should be able to just add another condition to the logic to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, you can use integrated Entity Framework's "Code first from database" function to generate POCO classes for use with PetaPoco. Just generate them and remove all unnecessary EF trash like DBContext and attributes. This way, you can generate POCOs not only for C#, but also for VB.NET and its all visual clicking, no messing with T4 Templates.

Project/Add New Item.../Data/ADO.NET Entity Data Model/Code first from database