# Create Pocos for Petapco with data (results) from stored procuders

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic-data, dynamic-programming, petapoco

I realy like PetaPoco, and I am at early beginning of using it.
My database server is MSSQL2008R2, and I there is havy use of stored procedures.
[I learned how to create Pocos from (for) tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10136520/how-to-automatically-create-model-from-database-using-petapoco-library) .
Is there an easy way to create Pocos from already written stored procedures which returning data back from SQL serve.

Answer (score 2):

The hard thing about getting POCOs from SPs is that you need to execute them with the correct parameters to get the results in order to build a POCO.

Are you aware that you can use a dynamic type instead of creating a POCO for every SP?

If a POCO is required, there are some tool that maybe can help you, although they aren't PetaPoco specific.

- [Code Smith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/) Generate code from SQL databases
- [SqlMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx) is a Linq to SQL generator, but generates POCO from SPs (use `/sprocs`)